# Connecting MVC Model View with associated Knockout.js ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Background: I'm pretty new to MVC & Knockout.js but I am trying to get up to speed on these technologies.  I am using MVC 5 with EF6 and Knockout.JS 3.2.

I have a Detail view that pulls a "VoteAnswer" object using MVC based on the ID passed in the URL:

For example I can go to the url MyDomain/VoteAnswers/Details/1 and it will pull the information from my database correctly (It pulls a VoteAnswer with the ID of 1) and display in my Details view.  However I am trying to hook-up my Knockout.js "VoteAnswer" ViewModel to function the same way and am having trouble.

Here is my Details View: (Note the @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VoteAnswerId) etc works and displays the data from my Database.

```
@model AM_SPA_TestSite.Models.VoteAnswer

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Details</title>
    <script src="~/KnockoutViewModels/VoteAnswers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h4>VoteAnswer</h4>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display Text</td>
            <td data-bind="text: isActive"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsActive</td>
            <td data-bind="text: displayText"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display Text</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: displayText" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsActive</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: isActive" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VoteAnswerId)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display Text</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DisplayText)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsActive</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsActive)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my Knockout.Js ViewModel

```
// VoteAnswer ViewModel
var VoteAnswerVM = {

id: ko.observable(),
displayText: ko.observable(),
isActive: ko.observable(),
SaveVoteAnswer: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/VoteAnswers/Create',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
            if (err.responseText == "Creation Failed")
            { window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/'; }
            else {
                alert("Status:" + err.responseText);
                window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';;
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';
        }
    });
}
};

//Go
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize and create new VoteAnswerVM by URL value here?
    ko.applyBindings(VoteAnswerVM);
});
```

I know what I am missing is initializing the ViewModel with the ID of 1, but I was thinking the MVC model already has the data and the knockout.js SHOULD map to that data without manually initializing by sending a request to the database again.  What am I missing?  thanks.

**EDIT**: **Added** **solution** **below**.  I'm not sure I am settled on this approach but here it is.  Updated the controller to ONLY return a view and not query the DB. (otherwise I would have two database calls for the same data.

```
    // GET: VoteAnswers/Details/5
    public ViewResult Details(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Added an API Controller that does query the DB.

```
    // GET: api/VoteAnswers/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(VoteAnswer))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetVoteAnswer(int id)
    {
        VoteAnswer voteAnswer = await db.VoteAnswers.FindAsync(id);
        if (voteAnswer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(voteAnswer);
    }
```

In my View (.cshtml file) I reference my knockout.js ModelView, View is Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Details</title>
    <script src="~/KnockoutViewModels/VoteAnswers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h4>VoteAnswer</h4>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td data-bind="text: VoteAnswerId"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display Text</td>
            <td data-bind="text: IsActive"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsActive</td>
            <td data-bind="text: DisplayText"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: VoteAnswerId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display Text</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: DisplayText" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>IsActive</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: IsActive" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated My ViewModel script to access the Database based on the URL ID.

```
// VoteAnswer ViewModel
var VoteAnswer = function () {
var self = this;
self.VoteAnswerId = ko.observable();
self.DisplayText = ko.observable();
self.IsActive = ko.observable();

self.SaveVoteAnswer = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/VoteAnswers/Create',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
            if (err.responseText == "Creation Failed")
            { window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/'; }
            else {
                alert("Status:" + err.responseText);
                window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';;
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';
        }
    });
}
self.load = function (id) {
    if (id != 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/VoteAnswers/' + id,
            type: 'get',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                self.VoteAnswerId = ko.observable(data.voteAnswerId);
                self.DisplayText = ko.observable(data.displayText);
                self.IsActive = ko.observable(data.isActive);
                ko.applyBindings(self);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                if (err.responseText == "Creation Failed") {
                    window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';
                } else {
                    $("#error").text("Status:" + err.responseText);
                    //window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';;
                }
            },
            complete: function() {
                //window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';
            }
        });
    } else {
        window.location.href = '/VoteAnswers/Index/';
    }
}
};
function GetURLParameter() {
var sPageUrl = window.location.href;
var indexOfLastSlash = sPageUrl.lastIndexOf("/");

if (indexOfLastSlash > 0 && sPageUrl.length - 1 != indexOfLastSlash)
    return sPageUrl.substring(indexOfLastSlash + 1);
else
    return 0;
}
//Go
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize and create new VoteAnswerVM by URL value here?
    var viewModel = new VoteAnswer();
    viewModel.load(GetURLParameter());
});
```

Comment: Is the ViewModel javascript in a separate JS file, or built directly in the razor page ?

Comment: have you tried `ko.applyBindings(new VoteAnswerVM());` something like this

Comment: @Robert - yes it's a separate JS file, I verified it is loading.  I also verified that the viewModel and knockout code work if I manually pass in parameters.  For example if I initialized like: 'ko.applyBindings(new VoteAnswerVM(1, "My Text", true));' and changed the function to except those properties.

Comment: I think your solution seems pretty good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly, if my answer is all wrong for your question let me know where I went wrong.

First thing to realize is, if you bind a KO observable to an input field, knockout will not look at the initial value of that input field and store it in the observable. It will do the opposite: it will look at the current value in the observable and store it in the input field's value. In your case, the observable are initialized without a value, which in JavaScript means the value `undefined`. So if you bind your observables to the fields you've filled with Razor/MVC viewmodel, you'll immediatly overwrite those values with the empty values stored in your observables.

There IS a way to fill your Knockout model with your data through Razor, but it involves inline JavaScript and is a bad practise for a number of reasons (I will elaborate on this on request).

The best way to do this is to separate your views from your data: Don't inject the MVC viewmodel into the view, but make a separate endpoint that returns JSON and return the data there (this endpoint will receive the ID parameter instead of the view). The JSON endpoint is called from JavaScript and can be used to fill your model with the correct values.

Upsides: separation of concerns, possibility to enable view caching for a more responsive frontend, no need to use razor syntax, or even worse, combine it with inline JS. All your binding of data to the UI will happen through Knockout. I learned this myself because we also started out using razor, but on the long run this solution wasn't feasible for a big project. We never regretted the switch to always getting the data from separate JSON endpoints.

If you are unsure on how to do this I can write some pseudocode to illustrate the idea.

Comment: never been through that line but i would love to see ur `pseudocode` if you can show us .

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans - So basically you initialize through  your own JSON call.  In my scenario where the URL is /VoteAnswers/Details/1   ("{controller}/{action}/{id}" from route config file).  Are you saying just manually parse the URL to grab the ID to initialize the knockout viewModel?

Comment: That's one way, parse the URL on the frontend so you know which ID to send along with your request to get the data. It seems from your code that you are creating a SPA, in which case there's usually URL parsing done for you already, so it might be easier to pick up on the ID part. Use the ID to perform a get-request to a JSON endpoint that returns the model that is now your MVC viewmodel, only converted to JSON (.NET has JSON converters aplenty).

Answer (score 0):

These may be the possible solutions

**1.)** data_bind is wrongly used

```
<td><input type="text" data-bind="value: isActive" /></td> // which is wrong

<td><input type="text" data_bind="value: isActive" /></td> //data_bind is wrongly used
```

**2.)**
 If still problem exists you may try this syntax

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsActive, new { data_bind = "value:IsActive" });
```

If you find still something missing please provide some detail info .